# d3.js - rect on exit() is not being removed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Problem:** Rect is placed on exit (confirmed with debugging) but it's not being removed when exit().remove() is called.

I'm learning d3.js and I'm trying to develop a simple dynamic bar chart with the json data below. My goal is to switch between datasets and and make the bars adapt to the values I'm passing, creating or removing bars as necessary.

```
var data = [
  {
    "year": "201801",
    "clients": 155,
    "trans": 344
  },
  {
    "year": "201802",
    "clients": 178,
    "trans": 334
  } 
];

var jsonTwo = [
  {
    "year": "201801",
    "clients": 155,
    "trans": 344
  },
  {
    "year": "201802",
    "clients": 178,
    "trans": 334
  },
  {
    "year": "201803",
    "clients": 191,
    "trans": 874
  }
];
```

When I create the first set of bars, everything is fine. When I update to the second set, the third bar is created. The problem happens when I switch back to the first set of data: the third bar is not removed. I have debugged the size of enter() and exit() at each transition, obtaining the following values, which leads me to believe this is working fine:

```
Number of blocks on enter: 2
(index):116 Number of blocks on exit: 0
(index):158 Number of blocks on enter: 1
(index):159 Number of blocks on exit: 0
(index):115 Number of blocks on enter: 0
(index):116 Number of blocks on exit: 1
(index):158 Number of blocks on enter: 0
(index):159 Number of blocks on exit: 0
```

The bars are updated in the code below, which leads me to excluding the possibility that I am appending rects on the wrong place:

```
    bar.data(jsonTwo).enter().append("rect")
    .attr('class','bar')
    .attr('id','alt')
    .attr("x", function (d) {return x(d.year); })
    .attr("y", function (d) {return y(d.trans); })
    .attr("height", function (d) {return height - y(d.trans)})
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth()*0.5)
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + ( x.bandwidth()*0.25) + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
        d3.select(this).transition().duration(100).attr('opacity',0.5).attr('color', 'orange')})
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        d3.select(this).transition().duration(100).attr('opacity',1)})
    .on('click', function() {default_show(data)});
   console.log("Number of blocks on enter: " + bar.data(jsonTwo).enter().size());
    console.log("Number of blocks on exit: " + bar.data(jsonTwo).exit().size());
    bar.exit().remove();
      bar.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.trans);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.trans);
        }
```

JSFiddle with the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/emfqpho9/5/

Feel free to give feedback on the code structure as well if you feel like it is necessary or part of the problem. after all I'm fairly new to this and every advice is an oportunity to learn.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you call `.exit()` (line 89) on `bar = svg.selectAll("rect")`, which is not a data join (it is just a selection). So, you should replace this with `bar = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data)`. I am not sure, that this solves your problem completely, but it is the first thing I am noticed.

Comment: That is indeed the problem! Thanks!